# Detect Ruby Memory Leaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, memory-leaks, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Ruby 2.3.3 and Rails 5.0.1. In my application the memory is increasing for each and every request and not reducing when the request is complete.

Installed Gems: (GemFile.lock)

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.1)
      nio4r (~> 1.2)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.1)
      activejob (= 5.0.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.1)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (5.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.1)
    activerecord (5.0.1)
      activemodel (= 5.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.1)
      arel (~> 7.0)
    activesupport (5.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.0)
      public_suffix (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.2)
    airbrussh (1.1.1)
      sshkit (>= 1.6.1, != 1.7.0)
    arel (7.1.4)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (9.0.6)
    capistrano (3.7.1)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      capistrano-harrow
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (1.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-harrow (0.5.3)
    capistrano-rails (1.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-ssh-doctor (1.0.0)
      capistrano (>= 3.1)
    capybara (2.11.0)
      addressable
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    codeclimate-test-reporter (1.0.6)
      simplecov
    coderay (1.1.1)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.3)
    database_cleaner (1.5.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.5)
    dotenv (2.1.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_girl (4.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.8.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.8.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    fast_stack (0.2.0)
    globalid (0.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    honeybadger (2.7.2)
    htmlbeautifier (1.2.1)
    httparty (0.14.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jasmine (2.5.1)
      jasmine-core (>= 2.5.1, < 3.0.0)
      phantomjs
      rack (>= 1.2.1)
      rake
    jasmine-core (2.5.2)
    jasmine-jquery-rails (2.0.3)
    json (2.0.2)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    libv8 (3.16.14.17)
    libv8 (3.16.14.17-x86_64-darwin-16)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    mail_gate (1.1.2)
      mail
    memory_profiler (0.9.8)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.10.1)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (3.2.0)
    newrelic_rpm (3.17.2.327)
    nio4r (1.2.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.8.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
    pg (0.19.0)
    phantomjs (2.1.1.0)
    pry (0.10.4)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-byebug (3.4.2)
      byebug (~> 9.0)
      pry (~> 0.10)
    public_suffix (2.0.4)
    puma (3.6.2)
    rack (2.0.1)
    rack-mini-profiler (0.10.5)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (5.0.1)
      actioncable (= 5.0.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.1)
      actionview (= 5.0.1)
      activejob (= 5.0.1)
      activemodel (= 5.0.1)
      activerecord (= 5.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 5.0.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-controller-testing (1.0.1)
      actionpack (~> 5.x)
      actionview (~> 5.x)
      activesupport (~> 5.x)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (5.0.1)
      actionpack (= 5.0.1)
      activesupport (= 5.0.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.0.0)
    ref (2.0.0)
    rspec-core (3.5.4)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-rails (3.5.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-support (3.5.0)
    sass (3.4.23)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    shoulda-matchers (3.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
    simple_form (3.3.1)
      actionpack (> 4, < 5.1)
      activemodel (> 4, < 5.1)
    simplecov (0.12.0)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      json (>= 1.8, < 3)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.10.0)
    simplecov-html (0.10.0)
    simplecov-rcov (0.2.3)
      simplecov (>= 0.4.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (2.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sshkit (1.11.5)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    stackprof (0.2.10)
    supercache (0.7)
    therubyracer (0.12.2)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thor (0.19.4)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.4)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    websocket-driver (0.6.4)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
    will_paginate (3.1.5)
    will_paginate-bootstrap (1.0.1)
      will_paginate (>= 3.0.3)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86_64-darwin-16

DEPENDENCIES
  airbrussh
  byebug
  capistrano
  capistrano-bundler
  capistrano-rails
  capistrano-rvm
  capistrano-ssh-doctor
  capybara
  codeclimate-test-reporter (~> 1.0.0)
  database_cleaner
  dotenv
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  fast_stack
  honeybadger
  htmlbeautifier
  httparty
  jasmine
  jasmine-jquery-rails
  launchy
  mail_gate
  memory_profiler
  newrelic_rpm
  pg
  pry-byebug
  puma
  rack-mini-profiler
  rails (= 5.0.1)
  rails-controller-testing
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails (~> 5.0.0.beta1)
  shoulda-matchers
  simple_form
  simplecov
  simplecov-rcov
  spring
  stackprof
  supercache
  therubyracer
  uglifier
  will_paginate
  will_paginate-bootstrap

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.3p222

BUNDLED WITH
   1.15.1
```

I used `MemoryProfiler` to detect memory leaks. I have pasted the result of `MemoryProfiler.start` and `MemoryProfiler.stop`. **Which one is causing leaks is not clear to me. Which gem or code causing memory leak issue?**

```
Total allocated: 242425441 bytes (2105822 objects)
Total retained:  2970695 bytes (16840 objects)

allocated memory by gem
-----------------------------------
  68444044  activerecord-5.0.1
  48631659  activesupport-5.0.1
  33867169  ruby-2.3.3/lib
  26983147  actionview-5.0.1
  20242402  i18n-0.7.0
  15872628  20170712102216/app
  10357404  simple_form-3.3.1
   3187323  puma-3.6.2
   3010603  newrelic_rpm-3.17.2.327
   2581225  activemodel-5.0.1
   2174325  rack-mini-profiler-0.10.5
   2077399  rack-2.0.1
   1785709  erubis-2.7.0
   1634373  arel-7.1.4
   1154020  actionpack-5.0.1
    209364  other
    122145  concurrent-ruby-1.0.3
     57606  did_you_mean-1.0.0
     16299  railties-5.0.1
     12261  sprockets-rails-3.2.0
      2808  honeybadger-2.7.2
      1160  sprockets-3.7.1
       368  tzinfo-1.2.2

retained memory by gem
-----------------------------------
   1102502  puma-3.6.2
    728109  simple_form-3.3.1
    522334  i18n-0.7.0
    226441  actionview-5.0.1
     93458  activerecord-5.0.1
     74910  rack-2.0.1
     70051  activesupport-5.0.1
     60945  concurrent-ruby-1.0.3
     31530  actionpack-5.0.1
     22331  activemodel-5.0.1
     12389  newrelic_rpm-3.17.2.327
     11770  rack-mini-profiler-0.10.5
      9717  ruby-2.3.3/lib
      1879  20170712102216/app
      1593  arel-7.1.4
       504  railties-5.0.1
       232  honeybadger-2.7.2
allocated memory by location
-----------------------------------
  16675773  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:176
  11287702  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:51
   6412328  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:123
   6169344  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/set.rb:83
   6122176  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:118
   5305392  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency/join_part.rb:51
   5249720  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:81
   4253488  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb:11
   4161024  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/set.rb:360
   3698688  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/set.rb:96
   3520608  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/set.rb:88
   3152622  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/simple_form-3.3.1/lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb:180
   2880280  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb:283
   2867056  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:145
   2866128  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb:46
   2818960  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:268
   2676232  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_set/builder.rb:33
   2662442  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:258
   2649672  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:69
   2593155  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb:192
   2389918  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:51
   1926400  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/set.rb:420
   1890554  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/server.rb:907
   1803634  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/simple_form-3.3.1/lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb:181
   1732528  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:198
   1599053  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:330
   1569960  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:72
   1508831  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:248
   1493725  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:109
   1462544  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:135
   1431338  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb:152
   1426240  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:5
   1402178  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb:654
   1373677  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:310
   1360800  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:161
   1353705  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:385
   1288272  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:24
   1280920  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:36
   1259712  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:67
   1244682  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/query_parser.rb:81
   1200960  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:140
   1156385  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:21
   1135632  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1867
   1086637  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.5/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:7
   1076640  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:32
   1067904  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:347
   1055840  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:89
   1050872  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:70
   1038184  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:14
   1035416  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:97

retained memory by location
-----------------------------------
   1050872  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:70
    516280  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:330
    435844  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/simple_form-3.3.1/lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb:180
    253231  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/simple_form-3.3.1/lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb:181
    112705  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:310
     31056  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.3/lib/concurrent/collection/map/non_concurrent_map_backend.rb:16
     28271  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/simple_form-3.3.1/lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb:183
     23673  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/client.rb:258
     22080  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.3/lib/concurrent/collection/map/mri_map_backend.rb:14
     19832  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:383
     18732  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/client.rb:285
     17776  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:165
     17640  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/query_parser.rb:64
     16944  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb:217
     14480  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access.rb:9
     14160  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameter_filter.rb:55
     13784  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/query_parser.rb:157
     11800  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:121
     11360  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.5/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:7
     11328  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:215
     11073  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293
     10975  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:340
      9440  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:141
      9132  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/simple_form-3.3.1/lib/simple_form/inputs/base.rb:184
      8914  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:347
      8406  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/query_parser.rb:167
      8110  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1889
      7776  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/client.rb:35
      6968  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:238
      6857  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.3/lib/concurrent/collection/map/non_concurrent_map_backend.rb:24
      5887  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:332
      5828  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:348
      5774  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/common.rb:384
      5680  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:5
      5664  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:269
      5360  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:80
      5360  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:676
      5360  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:683
      5106  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:33
      4720  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb:11
      4496  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:350
      4496  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:380
      4376  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:62
      3622  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:30
      3511  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/multipart.rb:36
      3280  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:123
      3024  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382
      2808  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163
      2551  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/path/pattern.rb:71
      2360  <APPLICATION_HOME_PATH>/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:139
```

Comment: Not an answer but checkout https://blog.codeship.com/debugging-a-memory-leak-on-heroku/ for more leak detection suggestions.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I can also see in my system that activerecord-5.0.1
 accumulates more and more memory over time

Answer (score 1):

Give [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) a try, you have various ways to see how your application manages resources, in your case you are probably interested in [memory profiling](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler#memory-profiling).